# How to check what is the default shell

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, chsh

Is there a config file that stores the default shell (bash, zsh, etc) for the current user ?

Comment: Terminals don't have shells, users do.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks, edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default shell used by a *user* is contained in the seventh field of `/etc/passwd` or its equivalent.

```
$ getent passwd xxxxxx | awk -F: '{ print $7 }'
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Is there another way that doesn't require access to such file like passwd

Comment: The *only* reliable place this information can be found is `passwd`.

Comment: When I install zsh how doesn't mark itself as the login shell

Comment: Did you use `chsh` to tell the system to use it?

Comment: Oh maybe it does that, that's why it asks me for permissions

Comment: So chsh changes the passwd file

Comment: @faressoft: You can check that with `strace`, for example `strace chsh -s $(command -v bash)  |& grep open`

Comment: @faressoft Please note you should always have access to `/etc/passwd`. It is where you user ID and username are mapped, and your home directory, and default shell, and it has to be accessible by a lot of things. You are maybe thinking of `/etc/shadow` (which is where passwords are stored) and that is usually not world-readable.

Comment: @faressoft In fact, when you log in, the shell you get actually *is* read from your `/etc/passwd`, via the same mechanism getent uses.